# How to pass data from Vue component to a twig function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '#my-component',
  data: function () {
    return {
      items: []
    }
  }
});
```

```html
{% macro page() %}
<script type="text/x-template" id="my-component">
 <div>
        {% pagination(items) %}   //<===== How to pass variable items to pagination
 </div>
</script>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro pagination(items) %}
 <select name="p">
 {% for key, value in items %}
   <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
 {% endfor %}
 </select>
{% endmacro %}
```

My question, how can I pass the variable `items` from my component to a twig function `pagination`.  I've spend few hours on this, but it still doesn't seems to work.  It should be a correct way to pass the variable from component to a twig function.

Comment: How do you imagine it? Twig is executed on the server side. Sent to browser. Vue is started there. You are expecting an impossible interaction.

Comment: We need you to draw seven red lines. All of them strictly perpendicular; some with green ink and some with transparent.

Comment: Great thanks for your response. I'll look for an alternative solution then.

Comment: It is possible to send data to server via Ajax to render new template and return it to Vue. But it is dirty solution.

Comment: Better is create own pagination component

Comment: Yep, that's correct. I'm thinking of creating a pagination component.